# What font does the macOS Character Viewer use?

Tags: font

What font does the macOS Character Viewer use? By this I mean the Character Viewer which you access with control-command-space.

(This is useful to get characters which look exactly like the characters shown there.)

Comment: Which version of macos are you using?

Comment: The font will depend on the character range.  Which characters do you need to match?

Comment: 10.14 Mojave, and I'm trying to match the unicode character ✓ ('check mark')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any character you can see how different fonts display it in the Font Variation pane on the right side of the Character Viewer, and choose whatever seems closest.

[image]